# regexp to find this pattern

Tags: php, regex

PHP => How can i search through this string in such a way that when i have `class="font8text">N</span>'` to give me 'EARLL' which is in the next `<span>`.

```
<div align="left" style=";">    
<span style="width:15px; padding:1px; border:1pt solid #999999; background-color:#CCFFCC; text-align:center;" class="font8text">Y</span>
<span style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;" class="font8text">DINNIMAN</span>
</div>

<div align="left" style="background-color:#F8F8FF;">
  <span style="width:15px; padding:1px; border:1pt solid #999999; background-color:#FFCCCC; text-align:center;" class="font8text">N</span>
  <span style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;" class="font8text">EARLL</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser -> Find an element with the right class and contents -> retrieve the contents of the next successive element

Comment: Weird, the question claims to be about PHP, but is tagged jquery instead. It can't be both, can it?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

Use a DOM-parser like: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

As mentioned ([a painless amount of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)). Regex is not a good way to parse HTML. Actually, you can't really parse HTML with Regex. HTML is not *regular* in any form. You can only extract bits. And that's still (in most cases) very unreliable data.

It's better to use a DOM-parser. Because a parser that parses the HTML to a document, makes it easier to traverse.

Example:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$dom = file_get_html('<html>...');

foreach($dom->find("div.head div.fact p.fact") as $element)
    die($element->innertext);
```

Comment: +1 for dom parser ...instead of [dam regx for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off using [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) succinct with each other.

Example:

```
$str = <insert your string here>; // populate data
$_find = 'class="font8text">'; // set the search text
$start = strpos($str,$find) + strlen($_find); // find the start off the text and offset by the $needle
$len = strpos($str,'<',$start) - $start; find the end, then subtract the start for length
$text = substr($str,$start,$len); // result
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
/class="font8text">N.*?class="font8text">(.*?)</m
```

`EARLL` would be in the first match group.  Try it on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/8wtWE89vBW).